# Change PHP variable inside an if condition

Tags: php, session

I have a system that logs in and depending on the type of user, a variable changes. It is either

`$_SESSION['login_type'] = 'MASTER';`

or

`$_SESSION['login_type'] = 'BRANCH';`

I would like to change the

`($rowOrder['merchantid'] == $_SESSION['merchantid']))`

depending on the 
`$_SESSION['login_type']`

so if it is BRANCH, it will be `$rowOrder['branchid']` and if it is MASTER, it will be `$rowOrder['merchantid']`.

```
<?php

foreach($lstOrder as $rowOrder) {

if ($rowOrder['status'] == 'PENDING' && ($rowOrder['user_cancel'] == 0) && ($rowOrder['merchantid'] == $_SESSION['merchantid'])) {

}
 }

?>
```

I tried:

```
  if ($_SESSION['login_type'] = 'BRANCH') {
   $rowOrder['branchid'] == $_SESSION['branchid'])
  } else if ($_SESSION['login_type'] = 'MASTER') {
   $rowOrder['merchantid'] == $_SESSION['merchantid'])
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

```
   <?php
     if ($_SESSION['login_type'] == 'MASTER') {
        foreach($lstOrder as $rowOrder) {
        if ($rowOrder['status'] == 'PENDING' && ($rowOrder['user_cancel'] == 0) && ($rowOrder['merchantid'] == $_SESSION['merchantid'])) {
    } else if ($_SESSION['login_type'] == 'BRANCH') {
        foreach($lstOrder as $rowOrder) {
        if ($rowOrder['status'] == 'PENDING' && ($rowOrder['user_cancel'] == 0) && ($rowOrder['branchid'] == $_SESSION['branchid'])) {
                  }

}}
   ?>
```

Comment: change == to = for assigning value

Comment: Use just one = for assignment

Comment: looking for an alternative since the one i tried gets "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: not a duplicate, updated my answer

Comment: If it's not a duplicate you should first fix all those syntax errors you've posted in your updated code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Change this. Use double `==` instead of `=` in if condition.  and Use single `=` instead of `==` inside if condition for assign value.

```
if ($_SESSION['login_type'] = 'BRANCH') {
   $rowOrder['branchid'] == $_SESSION['branchid'])
  } else if ($_SESSION['login_type'] = 'MASTER') {
   $rowOrder['merchantid'] == $_SESSION['merchantid'])
  }
```

**To**

```
if ($_SESSION['login_type'] == 'BRANCH') {
   $rowOrder['branchid'] = $_SESSION['branchid'])
  } else if ($_SESSION['login_type'] == 'MASTER') {
   $rowOrder['merchantid'] = $_SESSION['merchantid'])
  }
```

Change this Also

```
    if ($_SESSION['login_type'] == 'MASTER') {
    foreach($lstOrder as $rowOrder) {
        if ($rowOrder['status'] == 'PENDING' && ($rowOrder['user_cancel'] == 0) && ($rowOrder['merchantid'] == $_SESSION['merchantid'])) {
            echo 1;
        } 
    }
}else if ($_SESSION['login_type'] == 'BRANCH') {
    foreach($lstOrder as $rowOrder) {
        if ($rowOrder['status'] == 'PENDING' && ($rowOrder['user_cancel'] == 0) && ($rowOrder['branchid'] == $_SESSION['branchid'])) {
            echo 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that whole if is inside the parenthesis after &&, if i do that i get  "unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"